# App should not process with the previous input

Tags: android

I have 2 android app, by the 1st app we launch 2nd app's specific activity and after some process we again come back to 1st app, but when I long press to home button, there is 2nd app available when i click on it, again it go with the previous input and perform the same process,but after coming on the 1st app I already clear all the 2nd app data.

Please give me any solution.

Thanks

Comment: is nullifying all the variables in 'onStop()' method of second app not working?

Comment: Thanks for reply, but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

depending on how you are exiting the second app, you could put in `this.finish()` in the function that quits the second app. For example if you are exiting using the back button you would implement it like this.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    this.finish();
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: I am finishing all the activities and clear all the data before going to 1st app, but when I launch app form the recent app list, how its starting with the previous data.

Comment: could you post how you are exiting the second app

Comment: if(context!=null)
    ((Activity) context).finish();

Comment: can you give more than just that? like the function around it?

Answer (score 0):

In the manifest for your second activity set

`android:excludeFromRecents="true"`

This will make your second activity not show up in the recent Tasks list (long press Home butoon).
By default value for this attribute is false.

For other attributes check the link: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

Comment: Sorry But I need to show this in the resents app, I cant use this property.